# Installing previous version of iOS on developer device (currently 5.0 -> want 4.3.5)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I'm a registered Apple dev, and I got a new phone. My old 3GS currently has 5.0 installed on it and I'd like to put 4.3.5 on it for testing apps under iOS 4. I've downloaded the 4.3.5 ipsw, and using Organizer in Xcode I can attempt to install it, but get the "The Device isn't eligible for the requested build" error. The phone restarts and goes to DFU mode.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just a word of advice, whenever you ask a question, if someone answers your question you are supposed to give them the best answer thing. It is to the left of where you upvote answers. Do this for the first question you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download older versions of Xcode by logging into Apple Developer Connection Downloads you will need to be a member of the developer program to login.

[Here is the website.](https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?appIdKey=d4f7d769c2abecc664d0dadfed6a67f943442b5e9c87524d4587a95773750cea&path=//downloads/index.action)

Once on the site, from the Downloads section, choose Developer Tools – you will be shown with a list of all Xcode versions, back to 1.0 released in October of 2004.

Comment: Are you saying I need an older version of Xcode to install the older iOS? If it's that simple I feel dumb. Of course, I'm running Lion, so I don't know how far back I can go.

Comment: Well in your case the only way I know how to fix your problem is my solution... I mean I bet there is another way to fix it. But I do not know of one :)

Comment: That sucks... I'll check for another way to fix your problem

Comment: The version of Xcode doesn't have anything to do with the version of iOS on a device

Comment: Read hi question again @DavidDunham. DFU isn't working for him (if you know what that is) so something may be wrong with xcode. Normally his problem would be solved because of DFU but it is not working.

Comment: I marked this as answered per Gabe's request, however, I still can't downgrade my 3GS.

Comment: The link is brokenish.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to go from iOS 5.0 to lower than iOS 5.0 without going into DFU land, that i'm aware of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uT8Utk5Tqg&feature=related). (video on DFU mode - many out there as well.)
From reading, i'm not sure if the user can't get into DFU mode here - if thats the case, that is a bit of a blocker for ya for sure.  Maybe re-download fresh itunes and install everything 100% fresh, and try again.

Once it's detectable in itunes after the DFU (assuming DFU can be done), 
Download the firmware you desire it to run - 4.3.5 apparently?

Now, make sure iPhone is plugged into iTunes and iTunes recognizes it.

To force new firmware of older version onto the phone – hold shift (PC) or option (MAC) and click restore. This will bring up a browse box where you can select the firmware you wish to push to the iPhone.

This will probably result in a data loss though for anything on the phone before the DFU and firmware push.

Hope this helps, even though this is a few months old now.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google for 'xcode iphone downgrade' turned up [these instructions](http://www.tipb.com/2011/06/11/downgrade-ios-5-beta-ios-4/).

Comment: Yeah, I've been down this road and it doesn't work for me on Lion. Which is why I ended up asking on here.

Comment: Fair enough - thought it was worth a mention.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes will not let you install unsupported iOS versions (i.e. old versions),
regardless if you reset your device or not.

iTunes (as well as older versions of Xcode, like 4.5.x)
will let you choose a specific iOS firmware image (ipsw),
but when you actually get to restore the firmware, you get the message:

"**This device isn't eligible for the requested build**"
which is confusing, especially if you read [Apple's post about this error](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts4451)...

See this short article by [**chpwn**](http://mailto:chpwn@chpwn.com) that summarize it very good,
and also adds tips to try go around that:

"...with the iPhone 3GS ... as well as the iPod touch (third generation), the original iPad, and the iPhone 4,
*each and every firmware change must be approved by Apple’s servers, at the time of the install.*
And Apple will only agree to let you install the current latest release of iOS at that time,
which prevents downgrading — as well as any re-installs of the iOS release the device is running,
as long as that release is not the absolute latest version available."
  - *from: [How to test your app on older iOS releases](http://blog.chpwn.com/post/154128267086/how-to-test-your-app-on-older-ios-releases)*

Comment: Thanks, @Aleksandr - have updated the link to chpwn's (historical) article